# Can't seem to export my gridview to an excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Basically I have a webcontrol that contains a gridview with an export button. When this export button is clicked I want to basically convert the gridview into an .xls file so I can view the data in excel.

I've actually managed to get everything to work using GridView.RenderControl(); The problem is that the entire usercontrol's data seems to be saved to this excel file (including the button/images/headings etc). This isn't want I want. I only want to render the GridView data and possibly the heading.

Is there any way I can choose what information gets rendered? It seems bizarre that calling a function on a single control causes all the controls to be rendered...

Anyway here is my export button code:

```
 protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Exports as excel spreadsheet
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;

                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
                "attachment;filename=registered_subscribers_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Replace("/", "") + ".xls");
                Response.Charset = "";
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);                

                for (int i = 0; i < gvInterest.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    GridViewRow row = gvInterest.Rows[i];

                    //Apply text style to each Row
                    row.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");
                }

                gvInterest.RenderControl(hw);

                //style to format numbers to string
                string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
                Response.Write(style);
                Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
            catch
            {
                // Handle error
            }
        }
```

and here's my front end:

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ViewSubscribers.ascx.cs"
        Inherits="MyCode.ViewSubscribers" %>
    <div id="subscribers">
        <asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export" 
            onclick="btnExport_Click" />    
        <h2>
            Pre-registered subscribers for tickets</h2>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvInterest" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="gv-header" ForeColor="#ffffff" BackColor="#333333" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#e6e6e6" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HouseNumber" HeaderText="House Name/Number" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Address1" HeaderText="Address 1" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Address2" HeaderText="Address 2" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Postcode" HeaderText="Post code" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Comments" HeaderText="Comments" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateCreated" HeaderText="Date Created" />
            </Columns>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                There are currently no subscribers
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:GridView>      
    </div>
```

Anyone able to help?

Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I've done something similar to this (it was a few jobs ago and unfortunately I don't have the code).

You can write a method to take the output HTML from the gridview and stream it into an Excel file on your button's click event. That should drop the other controls off the Excel file.

Comment: When you debug it, does `sw.ToString()` give the correct html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this post here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/DipalChoksi/ExportASPNetDataGridToExcel11222005041447AM/ExportASPNetDataGridToExcel.aspx

You can use clearcontrols function to remove any html tags/controls/images etc before rendering them

Another link - http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2011/10/export-gridview-to-excel.html

check changecontroltovalue function

Comment: Although this wasn't the exact solution, it did point me in the right direction.

The problem seemed to be that the .RenderControl() function was rendering every control in the form. I just had to clear all the controls in the form then call .RenderControl() on the gridview and it displayed the correct data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

RenderControl is recursive, and there is no way that I know of to prevent it from rendering child controls/executing the gridview events you have implemented.

It is not really clear from your code where and how the images/markup that you do not want added top the export are being added. I have used 2 approaches to address similar issues:

1) Maintain a separate grid for exporting. render it instead of your display grid on button click.

2) Maintain an Property on your page that indicates a Mode. Skip any code rendering images/any other markup. You would set it to Export on the export button's click and look for that setting in your event handling.

Neither is a perfect solution, It is really based on the amount of coded you have handling to display, and teh amopunt of formatting control you need. You clutter your aspx with a grid, or you clutter up  your code behind with if statements based on this mode.

Answer (score 0):

The method I use is to export the data as a string with tab-separated values.